# how to train a gene dataset with a nearest shrunken centroid classifier?

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, data-science, bioinformatics

I have a data file named "geneexp.csv".

the data contains information about gene expression of three different cell types (CD4 and CD8, CD19) I want to classify cells by performing the nearest shrunken centroid classification of training data in which the threshold is chosen by cross-validation. I split the data (70% train and 30% test).

```
data = read.csv("geneexp.csv")

splitData <- function(data, trainRate) {
  n <- dim(data)[1]
  idxs <- sample(1:n, floor(trainRate*n))
  train <- data[idxs,]
  test <- data[-idxs,]
  return (list(train = train, test = test))
}

split <- splitData(data, .7)
train <- split$train
test  <- split$test
```

then with the use of `pamr` package I tried to buid the following model and plot :

```
y <- train[[ncol(train)]]
x <- t(train[,-ncol(train)]) 
mydata <- list(
  x = x, 
  y = as.factor(y),
  geneid = as.character(1:nrow(x)),
  genenames = rownames(x)
)

# Training and cross-validating threshold
model <- pamr.train(mydata)
cvmodel <- pamr.cv(model, mydata)
pamr.plotcv(cvmodel)
```

but I can't make it work. I get the following error:

> Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) :
> contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels

I have already transfer y to the factors. Can you help me? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code chunk might help solve the errors.

```
library(readr)

data=read.table("geneexp.csv", row.names = 1, header =T, sep = ',')

# Dividing data into train and test data
n <- dim(data)[1]
set.seed(12345)

id <- sample(1:n, floor(n*0.7))
train <- data[id,]
test <- data[-id,]

library(pamr)

x <- t(train[,-2086])
y <- train[[2086]]

mydata <- list(x=x,y=as.factor(y),geneid=as.character(1:nrow(x)), genenames=rownames(x))

# Buiding NSC model

model <- pamr.train(mydata)
modelCV <- pamr.cv(model,mydata)

pamr.plotcv(modelCV)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please expand the answer to include the "Why" and not just the "how"